# An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I am creating factories to replace my fixtures and to generate Test Data. I've installed FactoryBot but I am getting an error when running "rspec". This is the outcome log I get:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
  Validation failed: Email has already been taken
# ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'


Finished in 0.00041 seconds (files took 38.38 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

This is my spec/factories/user_factory.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email "peter@example.com"
    password "0123456"
    first_name "Peter"
    last_name "Example"
    admin false
  end
end
```

This is my spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe UsersController, type: :controller do

  @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)

  # let (:user) { User.create!(email:"achochaocierva@gmail.com", password: "Ratadecierva2")}

  describe 'GET #show' do
      context 'when a user is logged in' do
        before do
          sign_in user
        end
        it 'loads correct user details' do
             get :show, params: { id: user.id }
             expect(response).to be_ok
             expect(assigns(:user)).to eq user
          end
        end

      context 'when a user is not logged in' do
        it 'redirects to login' do
          get :show, params: { id: user.id }
          expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
       end
    end
  end
end
```

What would be the errors meaning? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the errors meaning? What am I doing wrong?

Your factory tries to create a user with the same email as one of the existing users (no wonder, seeing that the email is hardcoded in the factory). Your DB's uniqueness constraint complains.

You should use sequences for user emails

```
# email "peter@example.com"
sequence(:email) { |n|   "factory_#{n}@example.com" }
```

First user from this factory will have email "factory_1@example.com", second - "factory_2@example.com", and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for editing my question, sorry so much, I am pretty lost still...When I remove the factory "@user = FactoryBot.create(:user)" from the users_controller_spec.rb and use the fixture "let (:user) { User.create!(email:"achochaocierva@gmail.com", password: "Ratadecierva2")}" I get no failure neither errors. Any clue?Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Elena: this user has different email and, apparently, doesn't cause uniqueness constraint violation.

Comment: But I already added the sequence in user_factory.rb and keep on having failures when I use the factory "@user = FactoryBot.create(:user)"

Comment: @Elena: I don't think so. Sequences just work. Have you deleted the hardcoded email in the factory? Have you restarted spring?

Comment: I have removed the email, but I don't know what spring means, sorry. Anyway I think that maybe is anything else involved in the errors, anytime I use the factory and not the fixture there are  no examples tracked

Comment: @Elena: JFYI, use the factory just as you use `User.create`, inside of `let`. You really are not supposed to have them in-between examples like that.

Comment: Not working either, keep on identifying same errors related to the fixture. When the factory is used it does not identify the specs created for the let (:user)

Comment: @Elena: I'm not sure what that means, but I guess you're not having duplicate emails error anymore? Which is good news.

Comment: Still there, when I use the factory instead of the fixture same error occurs and no examples are found when I run rspec

Comment: @Elena: hard to say. It should work. If you make a [mcve], I'll take a look.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and will but for sure I will write a lot of info and you guys will kick me out of here. It is basically what I posted in first place. When I run rspec commenting out the fixture I get the error, when I comment out the factory and run the rspec using the fixture everything goes well, 6 exaples detected and 0 failures. Even uising the sequence.

Comment: @Elena: I can't run that :)

Comment: Thank you though :)